# scala, swing : thread issue with the Event Dispatch Thread(actors)

Tags: scala, event-dispatch-thread, scala-swing

I have a scala class inheriting from SimpleSwingApplication.This class defines a window (with `def top = new MainFrame`) and instanciates an actor. the actor's code is simple:

```
class Deselectionneur extends Actor {

def act() {
    while (true) {
        receive {
            case a:sTable => {
                Thread.sleep(3000)
                a.peer.changeSelection(0,0,false,false)
                a.peer.changeSelection(0,0,true,false)
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

and the main class uses also "substance", a API allowing gui customization(there's no more ugly swing controls with it!).

the actor is called when I leaves a given swing table with my mouse; then the actor is called & deselects all the rows of the table.
the actor behaves very well, but when I launch my program, each times the actor is called, I get this error message:

> org.pushingpixels.substance.api.UiThreadingViolationException: State tracking must be done on Event Dispatch Thread

do you know how I can remove this error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the gui update onto the EDT

Something like (I haven't compiled this)

```
case a:sTable => {
  scala.swing.Swing.onEDT {
    Thread.sleep(3000)  // this will stop GUI updates
    a.peer.changeSelection(0,0,false,false)
    a.peer.changeSelection(0,0,true,false)
  }
}
```

Some background on EDT can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html

Comment: the correct syntax is `scala.swing.Swing.onEDT {...`.thanks a lot!